# Dynamic width of a bootstrap 3 button to stay in col-md-* with long label on button

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a button that has a description (these are dynamically loaded) in it that is too long for the well that it is in.

Example:

[image: Example of well being too large].

I would like it to have it stay in the class="well" (col-md-2) that I put it in.

So for example I would like it to use ellipsis (or just cutting off characters) if it is too long to stay within the class="well" (col-md-*) that it is in.

Example if the full text is

[This is the description on the button].

It would display the following if it is to long for the col-md-* that it is in.

[This is the descri...]

I found this code to hide the overflow but it doesn't seem to work. Any suggestions?

```
.hideOverflow
{
    overflow:hidden;
    white-space:nowrap;
    text-overflow:ellipsis;
    width:100%;
    display:block;
}
```

CodePen example

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WGNgNG

Comment: Can you give us code to reproduce the error? Something like CodePen or JSFiddle works well.

Comment: @CalebAnthony CodePen example was added. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WGNgNG

Comment: you want the well and button to be in the same width and if the button width increases and corresponding width of well increases?

Comment: @Aravind no, I would like the well to stay within the col-md-2 and the button to stay within the well. The button text should end with "..." if the text would go off the end and outside of the well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this solves your problem

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <div class="well well-lg">
            <div class="btn-group">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle hideOverflow" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
               This is some really really really really long text<span class="caret"></span>
               </button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">some button</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">some button</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">some button</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">some button</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and this will be your css

```
.hideOverflow
{
    overflow:hidden;
    white-space:nowrap;
    text-overflow:ellipsis;
    width:100%;
    display:block;
}

.btn-group{
display:block;
}

.well-lg{
 overflow:hidden;
}
```

[image]

Comment: What will be col-md-*?

Comment: I don't want the well to keep extending, I would want it to stay within the col-md-2.

Comment: what is the problem your facing now?

Comment: @KevinVasko check now!

Comment: @Aravind thanks! that has got me 99% of the way there. The only problem is (which I can't figure out how to reproduce in the codepen) when the dropdown menu is actually selected, the dropdown box list stays within the class="well" and cuts all of the items off. I'm going to mark your answer as correct, but if you know how to resolve that, would save me a great deal of time. Thanks!

Comment: @KevinVasko for that you need to go to javascript and then change your height of the well div or u need to use css animations.

Comment: i have a snippet of that I guess you can raise another question for your problem! I will be happy to help you

Comment: @Aravind thanks, I would greatly appreciate that. I finally got the JS portion to work with bootstrap on codepen. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39301567/how-to-allow-bootstrap-dropdown-item-list-to-display-outside-of-the-class-well

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
.btn-group{
display:block;
}

.well-lg{
 overflow:hidden;
}
```

here is the result on my side. http://jmp.sh/HOownK5

Comment: Your codepen doesn't seem to work(link doesn't work for me, can't see what you have). But I added your suggestion to mind and it doesn't quite work. I would expect to be able to see the end of the button. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bwGxPY

Comment: Thanks! Your answer also works (it seems to be the same), not sure they were copied from each other but I saw the other before yours. But they both have same problem that when you click the dropdown box all of the list items stay inside of the class="well". Is there anyway to have the <button> stay like it is, with the ... but when the user clicks on the button it shows the entire list outside of the well? I'm trying to get a codepen but can't get JS to work inside the codepen.