# How to allow bootstrap dropdown item list to display outside of the class="well"

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

This issue stems from this issue. [Dynamic width of a bootstrap 3 button to stay in col-md-* with long label on button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39298332/dynamic-width-of-a-bootstrap-3-button-to-stay-in-col-md-with-long-label-on-but/)

Here is the example of the issue.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ORJagG

**HTML**

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-1">
        <div class="well well-lg">
            <div class="btn-group">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle hideOverflow" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
               This is some really really really really really really test really really really long text<span class="caret"></span>
               </button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">some button with really long text</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">some button with really long text</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">some button with really long text</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">some button with really long text</a></li>

                </ul>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
  <div class="col-md-1">
                <div class="well">
     <div class="btn-group">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle hideOverflow" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
               This is some really really really really really really test really really really long text<span class="caret"></span>
               </button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Should work like this but in the well...</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">some button with really long text</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">some button with really long text</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">some button with really long text</a></li>
                </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
.hideOverflow
{
   overflow:hidden;
   white-space:nowrap;
   text-overflow:ellipsis;
   width:100%;
   display:block;
}

.btn-group{
  display:block;
}

.well-lg{
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

Comment: you want the first element to be showed like the second? allow the dropdown to show itself out?

Comment: If I understand you correctly I want the dropdown to "show itself out". The information in the first box, the dropdown information shows within the class="well". I want it to show like the second dropdown box on the right. Basically, the dropdown box contents should show on top of the well. Hopefully that makese sense.

Comment: Is adjusting the `min-height` on `.well` an option? Like in this pen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BLaGVB. Removed the overflow and increased the min-height but not sure if that's what you're going for.

Comment: @wmeade your solution does work, but not really ideal in my situation. I really don't want to start hacking at the CSS to force this to work. I went a different route and simply used <select> <option> like I had originally and then used javascript to move to the anchor. There were too many problems with these buttons and I was worried about it becoming problematic in the hacks that I had to do to make it work. If you write out your answer I'll be glad to accept it for someone else that might run into this issue where this solution is acceptable.

Comment: No worries I understand that modifying the css in that way isn't an option sometimes. But I'll add that as an answer to help other just in case. Glad you figured it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Adding comment as answer in case it may help someone out in the future)

You can adjust the `min-height` on `.well` and remove the `overflow` on `.well-lg`.

```
.well {
  min-height: 85px;
}
```

Here's the pen: [codepen.io/anon/pen/BLaGVB](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BLaGVB)

Answer (score 0):

In order to solve this, it will be required to move your content out side of that main div element.

Keep in mind that children element will receive explicit CSS properties by inheritance.

Check in this Sample code, the expanded divs are sibling related to the button instead of children elements.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br>
<div class="dropup">
  <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu2" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Dropup
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu2">
    <li><a href="#">Action</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Another action</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>
    </li>
    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```